# Possibly a bug. PowerShell get-team searchs $filter=resourceProvisioningOptions/Any(x:x eq 'Team')

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

MS Graph API for Teams can create a team without resourceProvisioningOptions property set.
But, when get all teams with PowerShell 0.9.5(Microsoft.TeamsCmdlets.PowerShell.Custom.dll), it calls HTTP Get with "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups?$filter=resourceProvisioningOptions/Any(x:x eq 'Team')"
So, it cannot returns all teams.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I assume you want to list the teams by using the Power Shell.

I have tied this, and it works. First, I tried the following API `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups?$filter=resourceProvisioningOptions/Any(x:x eq 'Team')` on the MS Graph Explorer. And it works. Then, I tried this API on the PowerShell, it works too.

According to [this document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/team_put_teams),

> If the group was created less than 15 minutes ago, it's possible for the Create team call to fail with a 404 error code due to replication delays.

So it maybe the reason about you could not get all the teams